# Formatting String Date to DiffForHuman Style

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get dates in a format of '5 hrs', '50 mins', etc. I am fetching the data from api which is in a format of: `2015-12-16 19:28:16`

I successfully receive the value in a variable:

```
let date = post["created_at"].string!

print(date) // 2015-12-16 19:28:16
```

At this point, I found a library on Github called [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate). At the end of the docs, it explains something quite similar to what I want to achieve, so I tried:

```
let londonRegion = Region(calType: CalendarType.Gregorian, tzType: TimeZoneNames.Europe.London)

let postDate = date.toDate(DateFormat.ISO8601)!.inRegion(londonRegion)
let dateString = postDate.toRelativeString(nil, abbreviated: false, maxUnits:2)

print(dateString)
```

At `let dateString...` line, I receive an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

but it doesn't let me put '!' anywhere.

---

Also, if I `print(londonRegion)`, I receive:

> Region(calendar: <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x7ff09b414ed0>, locale: <__NSCFLocale: 0x7ff09b101b90>)

What am i doing wrong? What is the proper to achieve what I am trying to achieve? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I tried to search for it, but I couldn't understand the logic. What did you mean by "get the time interval for the date". Can you please give me an example converting date String to String like - 3m or 5h or 10d?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? If you have a date that you can print out as `2015-12-16 19:28:16`, what result are you hoping to get? "5hrs, 50mins" etc doesn't really explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem using this chunk..

```
let dateString = "2015-1-17 13:58:16"
let inputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
inputFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = inputFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!

let outputformatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
outputformatter.allowedUnits = [.Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second]
outputformatter.unitsStyle = .Abbreviated

var timeOffset = outputformatter.stringFromDate(date, toDate: NSDate())!

let first = timeOffset.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").first!
```